# ASP NET CORE Identity suddenly logsout

Tags: asp.net-core

I am using asp .net core 2.2 and Identity Core. I don't know what is wrong . when I want to login to Admin Panel, I do it successfully but when I click some link in Admin Panel, suddenly it logs out !! I don't know why this is happening . does identity cookie becomes null suddenly? what is happening really? there is no error in my web application. I mean nothing is shown in the browser . sometimes when I log in, I click links and it does not suddenly log out but sometimes it does .is there something wrong with the cookie? I'd appreciate any help.in my local computer ,everything works fine but on server I have this problem.
I put my startup.cs here so u guys can see it

```
     public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });


            services.Configure<CookieTempDataProviderOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            });

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddErrorDescriber<PersianIdentityErrorDescriber>()
                .AddClaimsPrincipalFactory<AppUserClaimsPrincipalFactory>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {
                options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
                options.Cookie.Name = "ghaschan";
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(120);
                options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login");
                options.LogoutPath = "/Identity/Account/Logout";
                // ReturnUrlParameter requires 
                //using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
                options.ReturnUrlParameter = "returnUrl";
                options.SlidingExpiration = true;
            });

            services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
            {
                // Default Lockout settings.
                options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
                options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
                options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;

                // Default Password settings.
                options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
                options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 1;

                // Default SignIn settings.
                options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
                options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber = false;

                // Default User settings.
                options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters =
                    "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+";
                options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
            });

            services.AddScoped<IDbInitializer, DbInitializer>();



            // services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

            services.AddMvc()
          .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
          .AddRazorOptions(options => options.AllowRecompilingViewsOnFileChange = true);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env
            )
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();
            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "areas",
                    template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
                );

                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
                );
            });

        }
```

this is one of my controllers in admin area

```
   [Area("SFAdmin")]
    [Authorize(Roles = StaticDetails.AdminRole)]
    public class UsersController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Would be nice to see what happens, when you click that link. Maybe your currently logged in user is not authorized and gets automatically redirected to login?

Comment: user is authorized and has role 'Admin'

Comment: If you do not post the controller action that is being invoked plus all relevant partials / helpers we can't help you.

Comment: check your cookies with name `ghaschan`.

Comment: the cookie with this name is created ,but it has problem somhow . some guys suggested me to use machineKey for webConfig

Answer (score -1):

I had same problem and it depended to server IIS. Shared hosts usually have limit on application pool memory, so this problem might be happen when fetch many data.